# Reading through shapefile table with Geotools

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-10.1, java, geotools, table

Goal: Read through a shapefile table with Geotools.

I'm confused about FeatureSource, FeatureCollection, and FeatureIterator in Geotools. 
In ArcGIS, I can open a table in an existing shapefile, and use a cursor to read through it, row by row. Here is the successful code using arcobjects jar & ESRI syntax:

```
IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace) workspaceFactory.openFromFile(fileDirectory, 0);
// field not found = -1
ITable table = new Table(featureWorkspace.openFeatureClass(fileName));
ICursor cursor = table.ITable_search(null, false);
IRow row = null;
int indexID = table.findField("ID");

while ((row = cursor.nextRow()) != null) {
    int idInt = (int) row.getValue(indexID);
}
// then do things with that data from the table
```

But in Geotools, I'm struggling to figure out, what is the equivalent? The FeatureIterator, maybe?

Summation: In order to read through a shapefile table and get data, what is the Geotools syntax?

Comment: The reason this question is tagged with ArcGIS is the use of ESRI java syntax as the example of what the goal is with GeoTools. 
Fields of a table vs. Features of a Collection is very unclear.

Answer (score 3):

This is easily learnable from the Geotools quickstart:
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // display a data store file chooser dialog for shapefiles
    File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }

    FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

    // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("Quickstart");

    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
    map.addLayer(layer);

    // Now display the map
    JMapFrame.showMap(map);
}
```

This code finds the file, and uses the FileDataStore to identify it's kind (here, shapefile). The SimpleFeatureSource featureSource  gets this source.

Then, you can reverse the logic in the Feature tutorial: [enter link description here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html) Instead of writing, you can read.

But in principle, you need to get a Feature Collection into memory, or use a FeatureIterator, and then access individual features from it. This is illustrated in the [enter link description here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html) tutorial.

```
SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = featureCollection.features()) {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            // copy the contents of each feature and transform the geometry
            SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
```

or to simplify, combined with the first bit:

```
    FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
    SimpleFeatureSource source = store.getFeatureSource();        
    FeatureType schema = source.getSchema();

    SimpleFeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures();
    // and here you can iterate through them and do things
```

Comment: You should always wrap your `SimpleFeatureIterator` in a try/finally block to make sure it is closed. `try(SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = featureCollection.features()) {...}`

Comment: In the example code provided in the question, one is able to get a value found via a specific field in a table. It is this specific use, in reading through a table & its fields, that leaves me confused in Geotools. I've searched and searched, but haven't found any syntax examples or solutions. https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/swing/table/FeatureCollectionTableModel.html

Comment: I'm just all in a tangled snarl, trying to find a GeoTools equivalent:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/923caa1a-642c-11dc-9ca3-0b35f906bb2e.htm

Comment: To access the individula values, take the SimpleFeatureCollection features, and iterate through them in a normal for loop, and access the values It does not behave as a dataframe (e.g., Geopandas, or an R sf frame). Geotools is not really aimed at a data scientists, the architecture predates this.